Why name the staves in LilyPond's "published" "Solo piano" template?
As part of learning Lilypond, I am trying to understand LilyPond's "published" "Solo piano" template. Lines 20-21 are:
 \new Staff = "upper" \upper
 \new Staff = "lower" \lower

I think, but I am not sure, that the = "upper" is simply assigning the name upper to the first staff. I also think, but again I'm not sure, that in this template these assigned names are not used.
Also, the pdf output of this template appears to be identical if I modify the above 2 lines to be:
 \new Staff \upper
 \new Staff \lower

So my question is:
What is the benefit of naming these 2 staves in the template as it is published?

You're right in thinking that the = "upper" just assigns a name to the staff, and so you're also right in thinking that removing the names makes no (immediate) difference.
However, there may be various cases when you do need to refer to staves by name. Probably the most relevant one is the \change Staff command which is used when you need to make a chord that occupies both staves, or a continuous run of notes that goes from one staff to the other, like this:

This is pretty common, especially in pieces of the Romantic era and later. For instance, all the 64th notes would probably best be written into the bottom staff (i. e. into your \lower variable) like this:
\change Staff = "upper" g'64 e' e' \change Staff = "lower"
c' e c' \change Staff = "upper" e' e' a' e' e' \change Staff = "lower"
c' e c' c' e' (... etc. etc. ...)

The \change Staff command will let you continue the run into the other staff, but you must specify which staff it should switch to, and for that, you must give the staff a name and then refer to it by that name.
A quite different situation where this is useful arises in engraving music for choir, where you need to engrave lyrics as well as music. Then you need to give names not to the staves, but to the individual voices, and then fill in the lyrics using something like \lyricsto "name-of-the-voice" { La la la, my ly -- rics }
(I guess there will be more situations like this, but these two come to my mind and I think they should be sufficient as an illustration.)

+1, those are exactly the two reasons for which I've had to do this as well. It is surprising for many users that the namespaces for command sequences and objects are totally separate, so that you have to declare the same name twice, but luckily you can usually use Lilypond without understanding too much of the underlying (very complex) object model.
